# What is this type of "return"? : Script ending with array [var1,var2]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm kind of a beginner in Javascript and I'm experimenting with various type of code to get an overview. I've come across of something that I can't find a definition anywhere for me and therefore I came here seeking for help.

**Context**: I'll provide a little bit of context to why I'm on this position, even thought it's not 100% related to the question: I have an Ionic 2 cross-platform application that should be opening a browser page of a certain URL that I choose, execute a script on that page to read div that contains a XML link and then return that string to me. To do that I'm using the plugin InAppBrowser and then I have an event listener that injects the code when the page stops loading.

**Function that will execute the script**

```
async doExtraction(fdsTask: FDSTask, profile: Profile, context: any, options: FDSConnectorContextOptions): Promise<FDSPromiseValue> {
    let script = EXTRACT_TEMPLATE; // extract_template is a constant of the script
    let iab: InAppBrowser = options.inappBrowser;
    let browser = iab.create(fdsTask.configuration.base_url, '_blank'); //this will open a page

    let promise = new Promise<any>(
      (resolve, reject) => {

    //this is when the script will be executed into another page
        browser.on('loadstop').subscribe( 
          (event: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
            console.groupCollapsed("Preparing to execute script.");
            console.log(script);
            console.groupEnd();
            browser.executeScript({code: script}).then((data) => {
              console.log("Executed script.");
              console.log(data);

              let result: FDSPromiseValue = {status: FDSPromiseValueStatusEnum.FAIL, result: data};
              if (data == null || data[0][0] == null || data[0][0] != "success") {
                console.log("No success. Rejecting...");
                reject(result);
              }
              result.status = FDSPromiseValueStatusEnum.SUCCESS;
              resolve(result);
            }).catch(
              (e) => {
                let result: FDSPromiseValue = {status: FDSPromiseValueStatusEnum.ERROR, result: e};
                reject(result);
              });
          },
          err => {
            console.log("InAppBrowser Loadstop Event Error: " + err);
            let result: FDSPromiseValue = {status: FDSPromiseValueStatusEnum.ERROR, result: err};
          });
      });
    return promise;
  }
```

**EXTRACT_TEMPLATE**

```
var xmlLink = document.querySelectorAll("div.exportLinkContainer:nth-of-type(2) a ")[0].href;
['success', xmlLink];
```

**Question**

The code that is going to be executed on the page is the EXTRACT_TEMPLATE above,
Since it is a script, I won't have any return statement, so I'm guessing that last array is the *"return"* of the script. My question is: what kind of syntax is that? What do I have to search to find more like these and find documentation for that?

Appreciate your help. Cheers

Comment: There's no such thing as a "return of the script". That code, if that's all of it, will do absolutely nothing except (possibly) throw an exception when the `querySelectorAll` call returns an empty node list.

Comment: Wait; not true; if it works it'll create the global symbol "xmlLink", so that's something. But that last line, with the array literal, does nothing.

Comment: It does work as intended @Pointy
That array will be present on the callback of the previous. And it did not create a global symbol. If needed I can provide more code that shows the callback (it's in TypeScript however).

Comment: Is the code in the question inside a function?  If so, you should include that as its very relevant.

Comment: It is @Amy , added to the post, thanks!